# How to reverse htmlentities()?

Tags: php, html-encode

For special characters like **áéí**, I can call `htmlentities()`:

```
$mycaption = htmlentities($mycaption, ENT_QUOTES);
```

To get the corresponding html entities:

```
&aacute;&eacute;&iacute;
```

How can I reverse this back to **áéí** ?

Comment: Which encoding are you using for `áéí`?

Comment: Do you mean this? `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en" />`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

Answer (score 110, accepted):

If you use `htmlentities()` to encode, you can use `html_entity_decode()` to reverse the process:

## [html_entity_decode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)

> Convert all HTML entities to their applicable characters.
>
> **html_entity_decode()** is the opposite of [htmlentities()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) in that it converts all HTML entities in the string to their applicable characters.

**e.g.**

```
$myCaption = 'áéí';

//encode
$myCaptionEncoded = htmlentities($myCaption, ENT_QUOTES);

//reverse (decode)
$myCaptionDecoded = html_entity_decode($myCaptionEncoded);
```

Comment: @Qix what's wrong in this example? What's bad about php?

Comment: @RNKushwaha the naming convention for opposite functions.

Answer (score 4):

You want to look at [html_entity_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) and worry about which charset you should be using (probably ISO8859-1).

It may also be worth reading [this article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) about character sets etc.

Comment: I tried this code but the characters stay encoded: `$strcaption = html_entity_decode($finalArray['Caption'], ENT_COMPAT, "ISO8859-1"); ` What's wrong with it?

Comment: The following works for me print html_entity_decode("&aacute;",ENT_COMPAT, "ISO8859-1"); you may want to check that $finalArray['Caption'] doesn't have things double quoted (e.g. ampersand characters represented as &amp; etc.)

Comment: `you may want to check that $finalArray['Caption'] doesn't have things double quoted (e.g. ampersand characters represented as &amp; etc.)` I think this could also be a problem. What should I do to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

```
string html_entity_decode ( string $string [, int $quote_style = ENT_COMPAT [, string $charset = 'UTF-8' ]] )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [`html_entity_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php).

Answer (score 0):

[`html_entity_decode()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php). This can be found at the very beginning of [the documentation for `htmlentities`](http://us.php.net/htmlentities)

Comment: Does somebody know why this is working `html_entity_decode("
&amp;aacute;&amp;eacute;",ENT_COMPAT, "ISO8859-1")` but if the same text comes from a variable it's not working anymore: `html_entity_decode($mycaption,ENT_COMPAT, "ISO8859-1");` What's the difference?

Comment: What do you mean "not working anymore"? It's likely that $mycaption doesn't contain the same string as in your first example. They may look the same on your screen but have different encoding.

Comment: It's getting closer. Problem: If I print the decoded it shows me the correct characters `$reversecaption = html_entity_decode($finalArray['Caption'],ENT_COMPAT, "ISO8859-1");
print_r(html_entity_decode($reversecaption,ENT_COMPAT, "ISO8859-1"));` but if I want to use it within the meta title it's the undecoded. `<title><?php echo $reversecaption; ?></title>` Does anybody have an idea why is that?

Comment: Uli: PHP doesn't know or care about your HTML. If you're using the same code in two places, it will output the same data in both places, regardless of the HTML tags. More likely is that your web browser is displaying them differently.