# php, how to convert special characters to text?

Tags: php, wordpress

xxxi have `the_title()` that returns some text, in this case `Blue &#038; Whiny`

the problem as we can see is that the & character looks different

how do i turn `Blue &#038; Whiny` into `Blue & Whiny` i tryed: `htmlspecialchars_decode(the_title())`, `html_entity_decode(the_title())`,`htmlspecialchars(the_title())` and nothing.

i want to convert `&#038;` to `&`

there is not much code to share, I just do this: `<?php the_title() ?>` and i get `Blue &#038; Whiny`. If i use `get_the_title()` it wont display anything

Any ideas?
Thanks

edit1. ill share some code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showShareUI() {

var act = new gigya.services.socialize.UserAction();
act.setUserMessage("Check out this article.");
act.setTitle("Trends on Explore Talent - <?php  the_title(); ?>");
act.setDescription("<?php  get_the_content();  ?>");
act.setLinkBack("<?php  the_permalink();  ?>");
act.addActionLink("Check out this article", "<?php the_permalink(); ?>");

var image = {
src: 'http://xxx.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/BOTTOM_BANNER.jpg',
href: '<?php the_permalink();?>',
type: 'image'
}
act.addMediaItem(image);

var params = 
{
userAction: act,  // The UserAction object enfolding the newsfeed data.                                           
onError: onError,  // onError method will be summoned if an error occurs. 
onSendDone: onSendDone // onError method will be summoned after 
,showEmailButton: true
    // Gigya finishes the publishing process.
};

gigya.services.socialize.showShareUI(conf, params);
}

function onError(event) {
alert('An error has occured' + ': ' + event.errorCode + '; ' + event.errorMessage);
}

function onSendDone(event)
{
document.getElementById('status').style.color = "green";
document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'The newsfeed has been posted to: ' +     event.providers;
}
</script>
```

I've tried everything. This starts to annoy me...

Comment: Have you tried `html_entity_decode(the_title())` on it's own? And if yes, what's the result

Comment: i did, i've  tried all separate, and it doesn't decode

Comment: What you want is to display `Blue &#038; Whiny` as `Blue & Whiny` or do something else???

Comment: yes, i want to convert `&#038;` to `&`

Comment: then just echo it, it'll get converted, without u needing to do anything else..

Comment: @Mick: FYI: Wordpress does direct output on its functions unless you use the get_the_whatever() version, which returns the data instead. It'd have to be `html_entity_decode(get_the_title())` instead.

Comment: nope, echo'ing it didnt work as well

Comment: html_entity_decode works, can you post some code attempting to use `html_entity_decode` to see what else it might be.

Comment: @ Marc B - if i use `get_the_title()` instead of `the_title()` it wont display anything. the same with `the_permalink()`

Comment: What happens when you echo it? Can you `echo "Hello World"` to check if it's an empty variable problem or an echo problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reverse htmlentities()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6465263/reverse-htmlentities)

Comment: @waitinforatrain will echo right

Comment: If echoing works but echoing the result of html_entity_decode does nothing, then I can only guess that the_title() is returning an empty string. Ensure you have error reporting turned on too.

Comment: @Patrioticcow Hi, check out the answer I posted. I tested it and it seems to work :)

Comment: `evil title"); alert("owned`. Or are you sure there aren't going to be any double quotes (let alone user content) in the title, or any of the other fields?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[`html_entity_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) is the correct way to do it.

```
html_entity_decode("Blue &#038; Whiny");
```

Will produce:

> Blue & Whiny

If it's not working, make sure you don't have another issue - such as passing a string to it that is double encoded, or running `htmlentities()` on the string again later.

Demo: http://codepad.org/BHXGWXJi

Double check with a literal string and `var_dump()` the output, you should see the decoded version. Then `var_dump(the_title())`, to make sure you are actually passing what you think you are to `html_entity_decode()`.

Answer (score 5):

[html_entity_decode](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) should do the trick. If not, try to specify the third parameter `$charset`.

Something like:

```
echo html_entity_decode(the_title(), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

Comment: This solution ended up working for me. If it's of help to future readers, here's my specific "Disqus" implementation: `disqus_title='<?=addslashes(html_entity_decode(get_the_title($post->ID), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'))?> | Company Name'` (`json_encode()` also works in place of `addslashes`, though the syntax needs to be adjusted slightly).

Answer (score 4):

[`the_title()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title) directly prints the title, so adding `html_entity_decode()` directly around that won't work. You can, however, stop it from printing with its third function argument. E.g.

```
<?php echo html_entity_decode(the_title('', '', false)) ?>
```

There's also [`get_the_title()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title), which doesn't directly print the title, but it requires the ID of the post you want the title of, in contrast with `the_title`, which prints the title of the current post in [The Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop). So you need to do something like this:

```
<?php echo html_entity_decode(get_the_title($post->ID)) ?>
```

And actually, you should be able to simply do:

```
<?php echo $post->post_title ?>
```

The only reason these utility functions are there is to escape things for you and add tags and stuff. If you just want the raw input, you can print it directly.

This won't fix all of your issues, though, because you're echoing it inside a JavaScript string, so you need to escape certain characters. [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) should do the trick, but see the question ["Pass a PHP string to a Javascript variable (including escaping newlines)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168214/pass-a-php-string-to-a-javascript-variable-including-escaping-newlines) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
echo(mb_convert_encoding(the_title(), "UTF-8", "HTML-ENTITIES"));
```

Comment: the same result, the characters don't get converted

Comment: are you sure you have semicolon in the end of &#038";"?

Answer (score 1):

see if this works for ya

```
$convmap = array (0x0, 0xffff, 0, 0xffff);
//$str = mb_decode_numericentity (the_title(), $convmap, 'UTF-8' );
$str = mb_decode_numericentity ("&#038;", $convmap, 'UTF-8' );
echo $str;
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-decode-numericentity.php