# Special Characters IE DB

Tags: php, mysql, internet-explorer, utf-8

I have a multipage-form in PHP where users can submit some information, I store this data in a mysql-database. But there are problems when I insert data (with special characters) in IE (chrome,.. works like a charm). The data that is stored in the database is correct (with the special characters).

But if I want to show this data again in IE, it changes the special characters.. I searched on the internet for a while, tried a lot of things but I can't solve it, so I hope someone can help me..

My **database** is: utf8_swedish_ci

The **font** is: font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;

**Content-type** utf-8

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
<title>Form</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8'" />
```

It happens with signs like àèöñ. How can I show this special characters in IE?

Comment: Try and change the database charset to utf-8

Comment: Have you tried the `htmlspecialchars` function (http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) or the `htmlentities` function (http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)?

Comment: database charset is UTF8_swedish_ci. First it was utf8_general... But that doesn't work.

Comment: I will double check the htmlentities.. I used this on the data of the db, I will try now before I insert..

Comment: htmlspecialchars doesn't work.. htmlentities does...

I have only now a new problem. I have an export to CSV, but this shows the htmlcode instead of the sign.. I have to convert it again..

Comment: I will check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6465263/how-to-reverse-htmlentities

Comment: Which version of IE?  What shows instead of `àèöñ`?

Comment: Terminology clarification:  `utf8_..._ci` is a "collation"; `utf8` is the corresponding charset.