# HTML entities to normal strings in PHP

Tags: php, html

I have a string with HTML entities in PHP. In html source i can see the html Entities but in the output my string is without html Entities.

like :

HTML source :

```
<a href="google.com" >Me&nbsp;You</a> ?<!-- output is Me YOU -->
```

How can i replace `&nbsp;` with  (space) in PHP? (as well as all other HTML entities?)

I want to have this output :

```
<a href="google.com" >Me You</a> ?<!-- output is Me YOU -->
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reverse htmlentities()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6465263/how-to-reverse-htmlentities)

Comment: @Jonathan: Not, possible, certain!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

> The function `html_entity_decode()`.
>
> This function decodes all the entities (including all numeric entities) that a) are necessarily valid for the chosen document type — i.e., for XML, this function does not decode named entities that might be defined in some DTD — and b) whose character or characters are in the coded character set associated with the chosen encoding and are permitted in the chosen document type. All other entities are left as is.