# How to render encoded HTML in browser

Tags: html, encode

so my task is to encode all html before inserting into webpage.

```
<!doctype html>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
  <title>The HTML5 Herald</title>
  <meta name="description" content="The HTML5 Herald">
  <meta name="author" content="SitePoint">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css?v=1.0">

  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
 <h1>wdw</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

i encoded it to below

```
&lt;!doctype html&gt;
&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?&gt;
&lt;html lang="en"&gt;
&lt;head&gt;
  &lt;meta charset="utf-8"&gt;
&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?&gt;
  &lt;title&gt;The HTML5 Herald&lt;/title&gt;
  &lt;meta name="description" content="The HTML5 Herald"&gt;
  &lt;meta name="author" content="SitePoint"&gt;

  &lt;link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css?v=1.0"&gt;

  &lt;!--[if lt IE 9]&gt;
    &lt;script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.js"&gt;&lt;/script&gt;
  &lt;![endif]--&gt;
&lt;/head&gt;

&lt;body&gt;
 &lt;h1&gt;wdw&lt;/h1&gt;
&lt;/body&gt;
&lt;/html&gt;
```

now the problem is browser is just displaying html as text and not rendering the tag. how i make it possible for browser to render it instead of just displaying the text

Comment: If the browser writes the code and not renders it is because it's being told to do so by your code, check: 1. any `<pre>` or `<code>` tag, 2. Check your http/httpd server version.

Comment: With php you can use `html_entity_decode()` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6465263/how-to-reverse-htmlentities or with javascript you can checkout this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796718/html-entity-decode

Answer (score 1):

**First Approach :**

**i tried to solve your problem by jquery but you have to add one unused `<pre>` tag to your code and two lines of jquery code**

if you ignore `pre` and `jquery script` on output then everything is as you 
wan't but it will display only `<head>` and `<body>` tag's 
and if your work is not done by displaying `head and body` then you have to go for ***second approach*** to ***displaying whole html code***

```
<!doctype html>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <title>The HTML5 Herald</title>
    <meta name="description" content="The HTML5 Herald">
    <meta name="author" content="SitePoint">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css?v=1.0">

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var data = $('html').html();
            var data = $('pre#display-code').text(data);
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>wdw</h1>
</body>
</html>
<pre id="display-code"></pre>
```

**Second Approach :**

this approach is *addition* and *Modification* of first approach 
and it take some rigid code,but it can able to complete your task at maximum level

```
<!doctype html>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <title>The HTML5 Herald</title>
    <meta name="description" content="The HTML5 Herald">
    <meta name="author" content="SitePoint">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css?v=1.0">

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var data = $('html').html();
            data = "<!doctype html>\n"+"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\"?>\n"+"<html lang=\"en\">"+data+"\n</html>";
            var data = $('pre#display-code').text(data);
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>wdw</h1>

<pre id="display-code"></pre>
</body>
</html>
```

***i hope it will help you and others***

Answer (score 0):

Your file is a text file and not more a html file, so the entities (e.g. `&lt;`) are taken literally.

So you should tell the browser that you have an HTML page, so you should add usual html boilerplate:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
 ... your encoded file
</body>
</html>
```