# PHP mail() can't find a solution for accents in message content

Tags: php, email, mime

I have tried many solutions proposed about it, but still can't find the one that works. The email is sent succesfully but accents are in html code.

This is my code for the email content :

```
        $to_APPLICATION_RECEIVER = "w@z.ca";
        $from_APPLICATION_RECEIVER = "x@y.com";
        $subject_APPLICATION_RECEIVER = "Subject";
        $headers_APPLICATION_RECEIVER = 'From: "people" <x@y.com> \r\n';
        $headers_APPLICATION_RECEIVER .= 'Reply-to: x@y.com \r\n';

        //define boundary
        $semi_rand = md5(time());
        $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";

        //tell header about $mime_boundary
        $headers_APPLICATION_RECEIVER .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n";
        $headers_APPLICATION_RECEIVER .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n";
        $headers_APPLICATION_RECEIVER .= " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

        //Message section
        //$message = utf8_decode($message);
        $message_hed_APPLICATION_RECEIVER ="\n\n--{$mime_boundary}\n";
        $message_hed_APPLICATION_RECEIVER .="Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"UTF-8\"\n";
        $message_hed_APPLICATION_RECEIVER .="Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n\n" . $message . "\n\n";
        $message_hed_APPLICATION_RECEIVER .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
```

The content of `$message` displayed by var_dump is `"sfdféèî"` but the email message content I receive is : `sfdf&eacute;&egrave;&icirc;`. Can someone help me with that? I have tried `utf8_decode()` and many other propositions on forums but still it ain't working. Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: Maybe try using `html_entity_decode($str);`...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reverse htmlentities()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6465263/how-to-reverse-htmlentities)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you view the *source* of the page you will see that your string actually *does* contain the html entities. `var_dump()` will have hinted at this being the case like so:

```
string(27) "sfdféèî"
```

You can convert the entities back to UTF8 with:

```
html_entity_decode('sfdf&eacute;&egrave;&icirc;')
```

Which yields:

```
string(10) "sfdféèî"
```

Comment: I used htmlentities() for security purposes, using html_entity_decode() won't cancel the effect of htmlentities()?

Comment: You *say* "security purposes" but you don't seem to understand what those purposes are. You should probably read up on that more, and re-evaluate your "security" decisions. Within *this specific context* it should be fine so long as you don't decide to change the email's content-type to html at some point.

Comment: Then whatever you're using to look at that data is not set to interpret it as UTF-8. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through